# How to get html using python when the site requires authenticasion?

Tags: python, authentication, web-crawler, lxml

I can get html of a web site using lxml module if authentication is not required. However, when it required, how do I input 'User Name' and 'Password' using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much depends on the method of authentication used. If it's HTTP Basic Auth, then you should be able to pass those headers along with the request. If it's using a web page-based login, you'll need to automate that request and pass back the cookies or whatever session token is used with the next request.